# no remote repository when installing dbweb

Tags: go, mysql

I want to install [dbweb](https://github.com/go-xorm/dbweb) to manage a MySQL database server but I get this error in cmd.
I tried to to install that on my go project and get same error.

```
C:\Users\NakhodaSokoot>go get github.com/go-xorm/dbweb
# cd C:\Users\NakhodaSokoot\go\src\github.com\lunny\nodb; git pull --ff-only
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
package github.com/lunny/nodb/config: exit status 1
# cd C:\Users\NakhodaSokoot\go\src\golang.org\x\crypto; git pull --ff-only
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
package golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt: exit status 1
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your git configuration. Can you go into each repo, make sure you're on master, and try to pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives those errors because github.com/go-xorm/dbweb has dependencies on those other two packages which it cannot update because you have them locally but they have no remote so go get does not know from where to pull the code.

Try removing them:

```
$ rm -rf $GOPATH\src\github.com\lunny\nodb
$ rm -rf $GOPATH\src\golang.org\x\crypto
```

Then try to go get your package again:

```
$ go get -u github.com/go-xorm/dbweb
```

Or go get them separately and then go get dbweb:

```
$ go get -u golang.org\x\crypto
$ go get -u github.com\lunny\nodb
$ go get -u github.com/go-xorm/dbweb
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i removed those folders and then just colud install nodb package. when i used `$ go get -u golang.org\x\crypto`  cmd get this error:  `no buildable Go source files in C:\Users\NakhodaSokoot\go\src\golang.org\x\crypto` and when  i tried to install dbweb i recived this errors: `package github.com/go-xorm/core: remote origin not found
package github.com/lunny/tango: remote origin not found`
what should i do ?

Comment: `no buildable Go source files` is not an issue, the other one should be solved in the same way, delete and go get the package again

Comment: thanks alot. i removed all relative packages such as tango and xorm and core and also dbweb and then install them one by one...the problem fixed.